# How can I pass Items from a set of Class objects held in a dictionary to an array?

Tags: arrays, vba, class, dictionary

I am trying to make a bit of a leap in coding from just using dictionaries (which I only understand in a basic way) to using a Class object to hold data.

I have created a Class purely to hold 4 items of data which need to be held together and then referenced later.  I then have code that creates a couple of these Class objects and which populate data into their 4 bits.

Here is my Class Module (called NarrativeGroup) :

```
Private pNarrative As String
Private pBillCat As String
Private pDateIndex As String
Private pFrequency As Long

''''''''''''''''''''''
' Narrative properties
''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Property Get Narrative() As String
    Narrative = pNarrative
End Property

Public Property Let Narrative(Value As String)
    pNarrative = Value
End Property


''''''''''''''''''''''
' BillCat properties
''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Property Get BillCat() As String
    BillCat = pBillCat
End Property

Public Property Let BillCat(Value As String)
    pBillCat = Value
End Property

''''''''''''''''''''''
' DateIndex properties
''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Property Get DateIndex() As String
    DateIndex = pDateIndex
End Property

Public Property Let DateIndex(Value As String)
    pDateIndex = Value
End Property

''''''''''''''''''''''
' Frequency properties
''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Property Get Frequency() As String
    Frequency = pFrequency
End Property

Public Property Let Frequency(Value As String)
    pFrequency = Value
End Property
```

I then have the following code in a normal module.  I am trying to load the 4 item types into an array and then to try and test if it is working.  My reason for loading it into an array is to then use a sub to output it onto a worksheet.  But the code errors! :

```
Sub setNarrativeGroup() 'to put the dictionary of Narrative object Items into an array

Set dict_Narratives = New Scripting.Dictionary
dict_Narratives.CompareMode = TextCompare      'make text comparisons so they are not case sensitive

Dim NewNarrative As NarrativeGroup

Set NewNarrative = New NarrativeGroup

Dim array_Narratives As Variant


NewNarrative.Narrative = "fee prep"
NewNarrative.BillCat = "Billing"
NewNarrative.DateIndex = "01.2015"
NewNarrative.Frequency = 3

dict_Narratives.Add NewNarrative.Narrative, NewNarrative

NewNarrative.Narrative = "meeting"
NewNarrative.BillCat = "Trustee Meeting"
NewNarrative.DateIndex = "02.2015"
NewNarrative.Frequency = 1

dict_Narratives.Add NewNarrative.Narrative, NewNarrative

array_Narratives = dict_Narratives.Items

MsgBox array_Narratives(1, 1)

Call PrintArray(array_Narratives, "Sheet1", 1, 1)

End Sub


Sub PrintArray(Data, SheetName As String, intStartRow As Integer, intStartCol As Integer)

    Dim oWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim rngCopyTo As Range
    Set oWorksheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName)

    ' size of array
    Dim intEndRow As Integer
    Dim intEndCol As Integer
    intEndRow = UBound(Data, 1)
    intEndCol = UBound(Data, 2)

    Set rngCopyTo = oWorksheet.Range(oWorksheet.Cells(intStartRow, intStartCol), oWorksheet.Cells(intEndRow, intEndCol))
    rngCopyTo.Value = Data

End Sub
```

I have tried to search for help on working with dictionaries of class objects and spitting them out into an array, but there doesn't seem to be much out there!  Any help much appreciated, and apologies for any big no-no's in my code above! :)

Comment: This [question and answer about class properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18385755/) should get you going.  Ultimately, you cannot use an index to get a property of a class unless you specifically add the `Item` property to do it.  As it sits now, your `Dictionary` is working perfectly.  Your access of the object properties is not correct.  I don't think dumping these into an Excel range is going to be as easy as setting `.Value = array` unless you specifically create `array`.  At best you will have a `Dictionary` of `Items` which requires a loop.

Comment: Many thanks Byron.  Do you know how I might place the class contents into an array?  I know how to then get the contents of an array into a range, and I also know how to get the contents of a dictionary into an array when the dictionary's Items are just strings or longs.  But when the Items are class objects with 4 elements as above, I have no idea what the syntax is for referring to them!  It's really weird because I would have thought I would have been able to find examples of class objects being stored in dictionaries on the internet but I've not been able to.

Comment: You should be able to create the `Item` property and then iterate through that with a `For Each`.  If you really want the array (probably faster to output to a `Range`), then you can create a property on the class/object which returns an array and just build it on demand.  Something like: `arr = Array(Narrative, BillCat, DateIndex, Frequency)` returned from the class.  The downside here is that you lose the benefit of knowing which property is in which index, but that doesn't really matter if you're just dumping to a `Range`.  I'll add some code later as answer unless you reply you've got it.

Comment: Thanks once again for your help!

I have created a function to iterate through the class objects in the dictionary and output them to a worksheet as below :

Comment: `Sub OutputDict()

Dim counter As Long
counter = 1

For Each strKey In dict_Narratives.Keys()
    Worksheets("Output").Range("A" & counter).Value = dict_Narratives.Item(strKey).Narrative
    Worksheets("Output").Range("B" & counter).Value = dict_Narratives.Item(strKey).BillCat
    Worksheets("Output").Range("C" & counter).Value = dict_Narratives.Item(strKey).DateIndex
    Worksheets("Output").Range("D" & counter).Value = dict_Narratives.Item(strKey).Frequency
    counter = counter + 1

Next

End Sub`

Comment: This works, but it seems to take an inordinate amount of time to do (as in about 3 seconds).  I don't understand why it would take so long!  When I am playing with thousands of lines of data this will be a deal breaker.  Maybe using class objects in the way I am attempting is just inefficient?

Comment: Can you edit that code into the original post and remove the comment?

Comment: It is slow because it is manually setting all the cell values one at a time.  You might find creating the array inside the class object and setting the `Range.Value` against that in one step is faster. It will go row-by-row or once per class object, but at least it dumps all the properties in one shot.  Ultimately, you use Class modules for their OO properties.  I don't think you can expect high speed from them... if nothing else you will have to create several thousand objects which is relatively slow in its own right before you even try to output the data.